# Disable running the scheduler on tomcat startup

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a scheduler to schedule the email service daily at a particular time. I extend `HttPServlet` and I am calling the method that run the scheduling in the `init()` method.

When the server is restarted it triggers the scheduler and sends email every time the server is restarted, also it gets triggered at the selected time.

Is there a different approach to disable running the scheduler on server startup

```
public class BatchJobsServlet extends HttpServlet {
        public void init(ServletConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        super.init(arg0);

        /**
         * TODO Assign to single node on server for Batch Processing
         */
        if(isBatchServer()) {
            initDailyBatch();
        }
        try {

        //

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        initDailyBatch();
    }


    private void initDailyBatch() {
        try {
            //Code to set the timer and trigger the scheduler
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

in `web.xml`

```
 <servlet>
        <display-name>BatchJobsServlet </display-name>
        <servlet-name>BatchJobsServlet </servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>...BatchJobsServlet </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may log the last time mail was sent, and check if after each `init()` call(restart) if it's the time for send mail or not.

Better solution letting native services do so, such as `cron`, simply cron calls a local app which the app will trigger the servlet(by invoking the path and a authorize token maybe)